# Many-to-Many Association To Same Model with ActiveRecord?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, many-to-many

I'm following [this tutorial](http://www.jumbabox.com/2008/06/ruby-on-rails-many-to-many-tutorial/) which is working splendidly for has_many :through relationships. I've got normal things like category_product working.

However, I am not able to conceptualize this situation (nor get it to work): I have a Category that has related Categories. Since every category can have N categories... first off, is this actually a many-to-many situation (I'm pretty positive that it is)? Secondly, what would this look like? My migration looks like this:

```
create_table :categories do |t|
  t.string :name
  t.timestamps
end

create_table :related_categories, :id => false do |t|
  t.integer :category_a_id
  t.integer :category_b_id
end
```

and my model's guts are

```
has_many :related_categories, :foreign_key=>"category_a_id"
has_many :categories, :through => :related_categories, :source=>:category_a
```

This is obviously not right, though it's getting there (i.e., it's 100% broken). How can I do this?

**Edit:** I forgot this, but only here on SO (meaning it's not the answer):

```
class RelatedCategory < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category_a, :class_name=>"Category"
  belongs_to :category_b, :class_name=>"Category"
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try `:source => :category_b` in your has_many declaration.

You already used `category_a_id` as your foreign key to the related categories table. This basically tells ActiveRecord to match the `category_a_id` field on the `related_categories` table to the current Category object id when fetching all related_categories records related to it. The source parameter to this `has_many :through` declaration specifies which field should be considered for finding (or writing, for that matter) the related objects when filling the categories collection.

Comment: +1 Thanks. That did not do it, but I'm beginning to look at the whole relationship again. When I used CategoryA it actually worked, it just never got the other side of the relationship. I'm going to run some more tests.

Comment: Sorry, your answer is right, but it's half the story. The other half is in my answer (below)... but yeah, very cool, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the answer, but it's not pretty.

```
  has_many :related_categories, :foreign_key=>"category_a_id"
  has_many :related_categories2, :class_name=>"RelatedCategory", :foreign_key=>"category_b_id"
  has_many :categories, :through => :related_categories, :source=>:category_b
  has_many :categories_backwards, :through => :related_categories2, :source=>:category_a
  has_many :category_products
```

then you would have to do some goofy getter that combines the categories + categories_backwards, or something.

**Edit [2 minutes later]:** Wow, with the getter it almost seems perfect! Of course, the problem is that you have to push to categories and not whatever you get from the getter.